# Showing Schur complement submatrices are invertible provided A has all its principal submatrices invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ whose leading principal submatrices are invertible (So $A$ itself is invertible). Supose that we partition $A$ as follows:

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
A_{00} & A_{01} \\ 
A_{10} & A_{11}
\end{pmatrix},$$ where $A_{00} \in \mathbb{R}^{[\frac{n}{2}] \times [\frac{n}{2}]}$ and the rest are also square matrices. Here $[k]$ denotes $floor(k)$, e.g. $[5/2]=2$

I want to show that all the submatrices of $S$, where $S= A_{11}-A_{10}A_{00}^{-1}A_{01}$ ([Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)), are also invertible.

Note: A leading principal submatrix $A_k$ of $A=(a_{ij})$ is a submatrix of $A$ in the form 
$$ A_k=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1k}  \\ 
a_{21} &  \ddots &   & a_{2k} \\ 
\vdots &   &   & \vdots  \\ 
a_{k1} & a_{k2} & \dots & a_{kk}
\end{pmatrix} $$

I have already shown that $S$ is invertible because both $A$ and $A_{00}$ are invertible, now I need to prove it for all of its submatrices.

Comment: Is there a reason that you expect this to be true?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $S_{k}=(A_{11}-A_{10}A_{00}^{-1}A_{01})_k=(A_{11})_k-(A_{10}A_{00}^{-1}A_{01})_k$. I was hoping to write $S_k$ as the Schur complement of a submatrix and use the basic property that the Schur complement of a matrix A is invertible provided both A and $A_{00}$ are invertible.

Comment: Ah, okay.  But there is no clear relationship between $S_k$ and the Schur complement of a submatrix.